# British National Grid and WGS84 conversion doesn't match in reverse in GeoPandas/PyProj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapely, geopandas

When I try to convert Google Map's lat/long into [EPSG:27700](https://epsg.io/27700) and then add a 50-meter buffer, I'm getting unexpected results. I noticed that conversions in pyproj between WGS84 and BNG are not reversible:

```
import pyproj
#Google Map coordinates of Borders General Hospital: 55.595754, -2.741771

#Projections:
bng=pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:27700')
wgs84 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')

#Google to BNG
pyproj.transform(wgs84, bng, 55.595754, -2.741771)
#Retuns
(8233971.054460906, -6088455.394871053)

#BNG to Google
pyproj.transform(wgs84, bng, 8233971.054460906, -6088455.394871053)
#Returns
(54.35845259494041, -3.0681078545288214)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of those BNG coords are valid.  Have you tried switching to x,y convention: `pyproj.transform(wgs84, bng, -2.741771, 55.595754 )`?

Comment: @JimT I think you can actually answer that, as that solves the problem

Comment: Thanks! What got me confused was that [Folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.6.0/) was displaying correct location for `folium.Map(location=[55.595754, -2.741771], zoom_start=15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinates are input in xy convention.  For geographical coordinates: x is longitude and y is latitude.  Try:

```
pyproj.transform(wgs84, bng, -2.741771, 55.595754 )
```